# Does food expire/rot in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

From playing the game, I've noticed that I can put food and other crops inside of a chest or my inventory. From what I've seen, it doesn't look like they perish, but I'm not certain if they do and I haven't met the conditions. Has anyone noticed if food rots, especially across seasons?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is currently (as of March 7, 2016) no rotting or expiration mechanic.

I have a chest full of foraged goods and crops (salmonberries, a few fruits, etc.). I'm currently at Fall and the salmonberries that I harvested in late Spring are still fine.

Comment: I am in year 3 and no rotting whatsoever has taken place.

Answer (score 8):

Jack O Lanterns DO in fact rot on day one of winter.  So as of this reply, there is at least one item that can rot.

Although it is not a food item, it will rot and display as a rotten item in your inventory.